# Laravel belongsTo relationship select orwhere

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 Models

```
class Computers extends Model
{
protected $fillable=['abn','vipnet_name','ip_address','serialnumber','zone_id','computer_model_id'];

public function zone()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Zone');
    }
}

class Zone extends Model
{
protected $fillable=['name','parent_id','is_head'];
    public function computers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Computers');
    }
}
```

every computer have a zone (In the Table [computers] there is a column [zone_id] that is a foreign key for table [zone]).

If i want to get all computers, having Zone with [zone].[id]==1 or [zone].[parent_id]==1, i am using this code:

```
    $c=Computers::all();
    $res=[];
    foreach ($c as $key => $value) {
        if($value->zone->id==1 || $value->zone->parent_id==1)$res[]=$value;
    }
    return dd($res);
```

maybe there is a better way with ORM query to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can [Query Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to get only the computers where related Zone `id` value is `1` or where related Zone `parent_id` value is `1`:

```
$computers = Computers::whereHas('zone', function ($query) {
    $query->where(function($q) {
        $q->where('id', '=', 1)->orWhere('parent_id', '=', 1);
    });
})->get();
```